# Suffix / Prefix / InBetween the .APK name when split by ABI

Tags: android, gradle, apk, android-install-apk

I have split my .APK file into multiple smaller sized .APKs using [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits.html#configure-abi-split)

As far as my understanding goes. The Gradle system generates multiple .APK files for different ABIs that I am supporting. Each .APK follows the naming convention as mentioned [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits.html#build-apks-filename)

Is there any way I can modify the name of the .APK files generated? I would like to either add a suffix / prefix / in between some string value which would help me identify the .APK being generated. Specifically the gitSha.

Comment: Have you already check out Build Variants? https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants

Comment: Yes, I have. But that doesn't help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, use `outputFileName` in your `build.gradle`.

Here's an example:

```
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.all { output ->
        outputFileName = applicationName + "-" + output.getFilter(com.android.build.OutputFile.ABI) + "-" + variant.name + ".apk"
    }
}
```

Assuming app name is "MyApp", APK name will be `MyApp-x86-debug` for a debug build for the x86 ABI.

Answer (score 0):

You can get Git Hash using command below in `build.gradle`

```
def gitCommitHash = "git rev-parse --verify --short HEAD".execute().text.trim()
```

```
variant.outputs.all {
    outputFileName = "ApplicationName-${defaultConfig.versionName}-${gitCommitHash}-${getFilter(ABI)}-${variant.buildType.name}.apk"
}
```

This would generate .apk filename be like
`ApplicationName-v0.1.0-e2c3b62-x86_64-release.apk`